# Nest updatebyquery how can i use a poco instead of writing the script

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have an elastic index with about 2 million documents, i need a way to update a list of them based on a single unique field. What i've tried is using the build in updatebyquery function in Nest, but what documentation i've found, requires me to write the update script by hand in my code like this:

```
foreach (var document in batch)
{
    var script = "ctx._source.brand_no = params.brandNo;" +
                 "ctx._source.order_no = params.orderNo";

    var paramDict = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
        {"brandNo",document.BrandNo},
        {"orderNo",document.OrderNo}
    };

    await _clientProvider.ElasticClient
                         .UpdateByQueryAsync<Orderline>(x =>
                             x.Index(indexName).Query(q =>
                                 q.Term(t =>
                                     t.Field(f =>
                                         f.OrderLineID).Value(document.OrderLineID))).Script(s =>
                                 s.Source(script).Params(paramDict))));
}
```

My problem is that my Orderline class is pretty big, and this hardcoded script is very error prone and hard to maintain.

Another issue is that this update takes a long time for 2 million rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that my Orderline class is pretty big, and this hardcoded script is very error prone and hard to maintain.

[Update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) only supports updating with scripts so you could implement a small component that generates the script from a given POCO instance, to reduce the likelihood of errors within the script.

> Another issue is that this update takes a long time for 2 million rows.

Would indexing documents into a new index, and [using aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) to point at a newer version index work in your case? Updating/Deleting millions of documents in an existing index is a *relatively* expensive operation.

Comment: This is what we went with instead, reindexing turned out to be a better solution

Comment: @JonasOlesen glad it helped. Are you using it for a search use case? If so, using aliases with versioned indices is a great approach here

Comment: What we do is, we reindex our current index, then we delete the changed documents from the new reindexed index, and then we insert them again. After that is done, we add the new index to the alias and remove the old, then we delete the old index.